# Which exact weapons do each alien enemy race has?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I've seen that sniper has an ability to disable main weapon and I was wondering which exact weapons do each enemy have.

For example **Sectoids** and **Flotaers** have a plasma gun but seems they don't have grenades... Do they have plasma pistol> If I disable its main weapon, will be they able to shoot with anything?

**Cyberdiscs** seems to have grenades, but I think I've seen them to shoot several grenades, so not sure if disable will let them to shoot grenades or not.

So my question is: **Which exact weapons (and in which quantity in case of objects) do each alien enemy race has?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aliens only ever have one weapon  -- this is what explodes into fragments when you shoot them.

Disabling shot will not prevent grenades or special abilities.

**Sectoid** / **Sectoid Commander** / **Thin Man** / **Floater** / **Muton** / **Heavy Floater** / **Muton Elite** -- Plasma Weapons; the same stuff your soldiers can use. Additionally, Sectoid Commanders, Heavy Floaters, Mutons, and Muton Elites have one alien grenade.

**Sectopod** - Sectopod Chest Cannon (they use a different weapon to reaction fire with; this one cannot be disabled)

**Cyberdisc** - Cyberdisc Cannon. Cyberdiscs also have one alien grenade.

**Chyrssalid** / **Zombie** / **Beserker** - Melee Attack (disabling shot not effective)

**Drone** - Drone Beam.

**Ethereal** - None (attacks with Psi)

Comment: Can all aliens carry different plasma weapons? I know Sectoids carry Pistols, Thin Men carry Light Rifles, and Mutons carry Light Rifles at first and Rifles later. Are there any other rules? Am I even correct?

Comment: Sectoids and Sectoid Commanders will always carry pistols, Thin Men will always carry Light Plasma. Floaters and Mutons will start with Light Plasma, but eventually move to normal Rifles. Heavy Floaters will carry Plasma Rifles, and Muton Elite carry Normal Rifles and, eventually, Heavy Plasma.

Comment: Are you sure cyberdisc carry only 1 grenade? I think 1 week ago I made a mission where disc throw two grenades at my poor soldiers...

Comment: @cad Nope, they get only the one. You can verify this yourself in multiplayer.

Comment: I was not sure... :)

Answer (score 4):

**Disabling Shot** is a very useful ability, but you have to be smart about when you use it.

**Sectoids** and **Sectoid Commanders** all carry Plasma Pistols. **Sectoid Commanders** also carry an Alien Grenade. You will generally not have Disabling Shot until you have stopped facing Sectoids regularly, and the Mind Control ability of Commanders cannot be disabled.

**Outsiders** carry a Light Plasma Rifle and an Alien Grenade. Again, you typically won't have Disabling Shot until they stop appearing at all.

**Thin Men** and **Floaters** all carry Light Plasma Rifles. Both of these appear throughout the game, particularly Thin Men who show up often in Council Missions, so Disabling Shot is a handy tool against them.

**Mutons** carry Light Plasma Rifles for the first month after they appear; after that, they carry regular Plasma Rifles. They also carry one Alien Grenade each. Disabling Shot usually forces them to spend a turn reloading, which can buy you that extra turn needed to get in close for a kill or capture.

**Heavy Mutons** and **Heavy Floaters** all carry Heavy Plasmas, and a single Alien Grenade each. As with Mutons, Disabling Shot can be handy with capturing the last of a group of either type.

**Cyberdiscs** have their primary autocannon, and an Alien Grenade. Disabling Shot is *extremely* useful against them, as their cannon spells instant death for even mid-game squaddies.

**Sectopods** have a particle cannon, a turret, and a mortar. The turret is used only on reaction fire and cannot be disabled. The mortar requires at least one round of preparation before it fires. Disabling Shot is situational here - if they try to use their mortars instead of reloading, that could make things worse instead of better.

**Drones** have their beam. They can also repair other mechanical units instead. Disabling Shot is generally wasted on them, as their beams do so little damage.

**Muton Berserkers** have claw weapons strapped to their arms. This uses no ammo and cannot be disabled.

**Ethereals**, **Chryssalids**, and **Zombies** carry no weapons. They also cannot be disabled.